# Always installing vscode plugin in docker container doesnt work

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode with docker container. I have following entry in user settings.json.

```
"remote.containers.defaultExtensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
        "ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters"
    ]
```

But when I build or rebuild container, these plugins don't get installed automatically inside container.
Am I doing something wrong ?

***Modified***

Here is how my dockerfile looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip
RUN apt-get install -y git libgl1-mesa-dev 

# Currently not using requirements.txt to improve caching
#COPY requirements.txt /home/projects/my_project/
#WORKDIR /home/projects/my_project/
#RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install torch pandas PyYAML==5.1.2 autowrap Cython==0.29.14
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.17.3 open3d-python==0.7.0.0 pytest==5.2.4 pptk
RUN pip3 install scipy==1.3.1 natsort matplotlib lxml opencv-python==3.2.0.8
RUN pip3 install Pillow scikit-learn  testfixtures
RUN pip3 install pip-licenses pylint pytest-cov
RUN pip3 install autopep8


COPY . /home/projects/my_project/
```

Comment: please include Dockerfile

Comment: I have added dockerfile content in the question. Is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 4):

This might be an old question, but to whomever it might concern, here is one solution. I encountered this problem, that particularly the Python extension from VS Code would not install itself inside my Docker container in VS Code. In order to get it to install the python extension (and for me anything else) you have to specify the Python version, like:

```json
    "extensions": [
        "ms-azuretools.vscode-docker",
        "ms-python.python@2020.9.114305",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
    ]
```

If you want to see this in action you can clone my [repository](https://github.com/yanniksuhre/bikerus). Simply open this repo in VS Code, install the extension Remote Container, and then it should start the docker container all by itself.